# flowtype error on react-redux 'connect'

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, flowtype, strong-typing

I'm trying to make my react native redux app strongly typed. I'm having difficulty to get rid of flow errors in `connect`

```
type State = {
  get: (thingToGet: string) => (propertyOfThingToGet: string) => {}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: State): Object => ({
  title: state.get('alertModal').get('alertModalTitle'),
  isOpen: state.get('alertModal').get('isAlertModalOpen'),
  message: state.get('alertModal').get('alertModalMessage'),
  viewHeight: state.get('alertModal').get('height'),
  hasYesNo: state.get('alertModal').get('hasYesNo')
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<*>): Object => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updateAlertModalHeight,
      updateAlertModalIsOpen
    },
    dispatch
  )
}

type Props = {
  isOpen: boolean,
  title: string,
  message: string,
  viewHeight: number,
  updateAlertModalHeight: () => {},
  hasYesNo: boolean,
  yesClicked: boolean,
  updateAlertModalIsOpen: () => {}
}

class AlertModal extends Component<Props, State> {
  render(): React$Element<*> {
    console.log('AlertModal')
    return (
      <View style={alertModalStyle.container}>
        <PresentationalModal
          style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
          isOpen={this.props.isOpen}
          title={this.props.title}
          message={this.props.message}
          updateAlertModalHeight={this.props.updateAlertModalHeight}
          viewHeight={this.props.viewHeight}
          hasYesNo={this.props.hasYesNo}
          yesClicked={this.props.yesClicked}
          updateAlertModalIsOpen={this.props.updateAlertModalIsOpen}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AlertModal)
```

On the bottom line of that code I get this error:

> [flow] call of call of `connect` (Function cannot be called on any
>   member of intersection type intersection Member 1: function type
>   Error: function type Callable signature not found in statics of
>   `AlertModal` Member 2: function type Error: React.Component Too many
>   type arguments. Expected at most 2 See type parameters of definition
>   here)

I've been looking online for solutions but a lot of them seem abstruse and involved for a beginner like me so I couldn't manage to implement them in my code without causing flow errors. How do I get rid of the flow error?